# PHP - Iterating Over Arrays and Transposing Array Data in HTML Table

Tags: php, arrays, iteration

I am a bit stuck and need your help! I have an array of students:

Students:

> ```
>   Array
>   (
>       [John]
>       [Jerry]
>       [Sam]
>       [Amanda]
>   )
> ```

I iterate over each of the students (no problems here...) and for each student, I have their meal schedule for two weeks (in the array below, I have a schedule for John (only) from 31st March till 13th of April --- Jerry, Sam, and Amanda's are in the same structure, but with different values etc.)

Meal Schedule:

> ```
> Array
> (
> [31-MAR-17] => Array
>     (
>         [Apples] => 1
>         [Oranges] => 
>         [Peaches] => 
>         [Berries] => 
>     )
> ```

```
[01-APR-17] => Array
    (
        [Apples] => 
        [Oranges] => 
        [Peaches] => 2
        [Berries] => 
    )

[02-APR-17] => Array
    (
        [Apples] => 
        [Oranges] => 2
        [Peaches] => 
        [Berries] => 
    )

[03-APR-17] => Array
    (
        [Apples] => 2
        [Oranges] => 
        [Peaches] => 2
        [Berries] => 
    )

[04-APR-17] => Array
    (
        [Apples] => 
        [Oranges] => 
        [Peaches] => 
        [Berries] => 50
    )

[05-APR-17] => Array
    (
        [Apples] => 1
        [Oranges] => 1
        [Peaches] => 1
        [Berries] => 
    )

[06-APR-17] => Array
    (
        [Apples] => 
        [Oranges] => 2
        [Peaches] => 
        [Berries] => 
    )

[07-APR-17] => Array
    (
        [Apples] => 
        [Oranges] => 
        [Peaches] => 
        [Berries] => 50
    )

[08-APR-17] => Array
    (
        [Apples] => 
        [Oranges] => 
        [Peaches] => 3
        [Berries] => 
    )

[09-APR-17] => Array
    (
        [Apples] => 3
        [Oranges] => 
        [Peaches] => 
        [Berries] => 20
    )

[10-APR-17] => Array
    (
        [Apples] => 
        [Oranges] => 2
        [Peaches] => 
        [Berries] => 15
    )

[11-APR-17] => Array
    (
        [Apples] => 
        [Oranges] => 
        [Peaches] => 1
        [Berries] => 20
    )

[12-APR-17] => Array
    (
        [Apples] => 2
        [Oranges] => 3
        [Peaches] => 
        [Berries] => 
    )

[13-APR-17] => Array
    (
        [Apples] => 1
        [Oranges] => 
        [Peaches] => 2
        [Berries] => 
    )
```

)

Here's where I am stuck--

I need the layout to be as follows:

[image: Desired Output]

and the same desired output would be displayed for the other three students... based on their own meal schedules

I have researched and have yet to come across a similar scenario on this site or on the net.

How can I go about achieving this? Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Nested loops. The row loop iterates over the fruits, the column loops over the dates.

Comment: @Barmar-- Any code example would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <?php foreach ($johnArray as $date=>$food) { ?>
       <td><?= date('m/d', strtotime($date)) ?></td>
       <?php } ?>
       <td>Type</td>
   </tr>
   <!-- Apple row -->
   <tr>
       <?php foreach ($johnArray as $date=>$food) { ?>
       <td><?= $food['Apples'] ?></td>
       <?php } ?>
       <td>Apple</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

This is just a snippet to help you get started. You should be able to figure the other rows out yourself.

This example is for one person (im assuming each person has their own table).
You first generate the first row with the dates, followed by the Type column. So you loop through the dates, which is the key in the array and create a column for each date. After which you add the column for Type.

You do the same approach for the food values as well.

Comment: That's all I was looking for... a hint in the right direction; Barmar's comment was a little vague. Thanks Prem Raj!